# pygame time.sleep prioritised over the rest of the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, pygame

I am trying to create a quiz app where you press either one of two buttons. This is the MVC example. The main issue is with the 'correct' function. I intended to have it set question to false (which didn't solve the issue), fill the game display, then print out a message to the screen, and update the display, to have it wait 3 seconds before doing anything else. But instead, it waits 3 seconds, flashes the intended screen for a single tick then instantly goes back to the question function. Isn't python supposed to read the function line by line from top to bottom? Because right now it prioritises time.sleep over the rest of the instructions in the function

```
import time
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
display_width = 800
display_height = 600
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))

def question():
    global question
    question = True
    while question:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(cyan)
        button('text', 150, 500, 100, 50, darkYellow, yellow, action = 'correct')
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(100)


def button(text, x, y, width, height, inactive_color, active_color, action = None):
    cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x + width > cur[0] > x and y + height > cur[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, active_color, (x, y, width, height))
        pygame.display.update()
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == 'correct':
                question = False
                correct()
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, inactive_color, (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()

def correct():
    question = False
    gameDisplay.fill(cyan)
    message_to_screen('Both of these licenses allow for distribution of software', black)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(3)

question()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Because right now it prioritises time.sleep over the rest of the instructions in the function

I don't know exactly what you expect what `time.sleep` does. It will simply halt your game, and during this time, basically nothing happens. 'Nothing happens' includes drawing and event handling. Nothing is "prioritized".

Remember theses simple rules:

- Whenever you use `time.sleep` in a game, it's probably wrong
- Whenever you call `pygame.display.update`  multiple times, it's probably wrong

You have to keep track of the *state* of your game, and each frame decide what to do based on tis state. In the simplest form, this state is simple one or more variables.

Here's a simple, runnable and generic example:

```
import time
import pygame
import pygame.freetype
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
display_width = 800
display_height = 600
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
font = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 20)

def question():
    global question
    question = True
    state = None
    while question:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        gameDisplay.fill(pygame.Color('cyan'))
        result = button('text', 150, 500, 100, 50, pygame.Color('grey'), pygame.Color('yellow'), action = correct)
        if result: state = result
        if state: question = state()
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(100)


def button(text, x, y, width, height, inactive_color, active_color, action = None):
    cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x + width > cur[0] > x and y + height > cur[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, active_color, (x, y, width, height))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            return action()
        return None
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, inactive_color, (x, y, width, height))

def message_to_screen(text, color):
    font.render_to(gameDisplay, (100, 100), text, color)

def correct():
    start = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    def func():
        cur = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        message_to_screen('Both of these licenses allow for distribution of software', pygame.Color('black'))
        return cur - start < 3000

    return func

question()
```

We pass the `button` function another function (in this case, `correct`), which will be called if the player clicks the button.

The result of this, which in turn is also a function, is then stored in the variable `state` and supposed to return `True` to keep the game running or `False` to end the game. This is done by setting `question` to the result of that function call.

Of course there are endless ways to to something like this, but this double function approach has the advantage to keep the `button` function generic and encapsulate the state ("how long are we going to display the message") in the `correct` function. You'll get the idea.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. I have a different project where I have multiple time.sleep statements in one function and it works exactly as intended. I expect python to read through the instructions line by line, and for the time.sleep function to simply halt the game and then continue with the instructions below it